# Custom font with css not work in Sphinx project

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I maked a Sphinx (Readthedocs) project with custom font.

Exported - http://1ra-manual-dentrenament-basic-de-combat.readthedocs.io/ca/latest/

Github - https://github.com/CavallersDelCel/1RA_EBC/blob/master/docs/index.rst

Custom font in `_static/fonts/LinBiolinum_Kah.ttf`

I have a _static/css/custom.css with:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Linux Biolinum Keyboard";
    src: url(../fonts/LinBiolinum_Kah.ttf);
}

.keys {
  font-family: "Linux Biolinum Keyboard", sans-serif;
}
```

In conf.py i have:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('css/custom.css')
```

And in one page i write:

```
<span class="keys">FM</span>
```

But the result is a plain text with the tags, not text with the custom font:

[html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJWAE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.

1. Docutils (the library that Sphinx uses to convert reStructuredText to HTML) converts quotes to their localized typographical version.  In this case `"` gets converted to `»`.
2. You expect that text does not get HTML-encoded, but Sphinx will convert HTML entities (`<` and `>`) from plain text to their HTML-encoded entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

To correct the issue in this case, you probably want to use the [`.. raw::` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through), like so:

```
.. raw:: html

    <span class="keys">FM</span>
```

...and then Sphinx should allow the HTML code to render properly.

Additionally if you want to show the source HTML code inline:

```
.. code-block:: html

    <span class="keys">FM</span>
```

Comment: This work in a single line. But i need include this custom font between normal font. For example:

`Press F to change fire mode.`

How could this be done?

Comment: You can create a custom role

    .. role:: raw-html(raw)
       :format: html

    Press :raw-html:`<span class="keys">F</span>` to change

The output code doesn't look right on the comment. Here you can find more information http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw

Comment: Also Sphinx has a kbd role, probably is what you want http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-kbd

Comment: This solution only work in my project at local. When i upload the page and the new css to the github, this not show well.

[This is local](https://i.imgur.com/XyucZBQ.png?1), [and this is online](https://i.imgur.com/dgT6JXB.png?1)

And the other problem is the PDF not render this kbd system and the own font. [This is PDF](https://i.imgur.com/5uHoSw1.png?1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler and more precise way to do this.

Let me review the background, mostly from the question:

1. Transfer the font to the fonts folder. In my set-up, it is found in the build folder, build/_static/fonts.
2. In source/_static/css/, create or edit a file custom.css.
3. Add the lines:

   ```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Linux Biolinum Keyboard";
        src: url(../fonts/LinBiolinum_Kah.ttf);
    }

    .keys {
        font-family: "Linux Biolinum Keyboard", sans-serif;
    }
   ```
4. Assuming that you want HTML output, make sure that conf.py has these lines under "Options of HTML output":

   ```
    html_css_files = ['css/custom.css',]
    html_static_path = ['_static']
   ```

Now for the trick.

5. In conf.py, define a role for the font in `rst.prolog`:

   ```
    rst_prolog = """
       .. role:: LBK
           :class: keys
    """
   ```
6. This role can be invoked in any document in the project, in one of two ways:

a. by applying the role to a bit of text, eg.

```
    :LBK:`FM`
```

b. by appending the class option to a body element, eg.

```
    .. list-table:: My Table
        :header-rows: 1
        :widths: 20 20
        :class: keys
```